# Why are some tables missing in the list of tables?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

In the thesis I am writing, I have a few tables that I would like to see listed at the beginning. To do so, I use the command

```
\listoftables
```

However, only one table is listed and all the others are not. This is still the case even after multiple compilation. I cannot tell the difference between my tables, since I used a correct caption everywhere.

What could be a possible reason for this? How can I make all the tables be listed?

I did not use the following commands:

```
\captionsetup[table]{list=no}
\nofiles
\includeonly
```

Comment: You should compile at least twice in your first go. And, at least twice for page numbers to be correct. After compiling twice, are the tables present in the List of Tables?

Comment: clearly that shouldn't happen given the correct markup, so markup must be incorrect somewhere, perhaps you are using \includeonly or \nofiles, or \caption isn't as correct as you hope, or something else you haven't shown is wrong, or you haven't run latex enough times or.....

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or select your code and hit Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was that the rest of the tables were after the `\end{document}` command…

Thank you for your help anyway.